# jQuery adding variables

Tags: jquery

I have used following code to add three variables but instead of adding these variables its concatenating these variables.

```
var registration_fee = $('input[type="radio"][name="registration_fee"]:checked').val();
var material_fee = $('input[type="radio"][name="material_fee"]:checked').val();
var tuition_fee = $('input[type="radio"][name="tuition_fee"]:checked').val();
// alert(tuition_fee)
var total_fee = registration_fee + material_fee + tuition_fee;
$('#total_fee').html(total_fee);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cast them to numbers using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
var total_fee = parseInt(registration_fee) + parseInt(material_fee) + parseInt(tuition_fee);
```

Comment: BUt if I have used ,val() whats need to parse it than?

Comment: Or if you want something more compact you can always use the unary plus operator. I'd suggest doing the conversion from string to number at the time you set the variable values, so like this: `var tuition_fee = +$('input[type="radio"][name="tuition_fee"]:checked').val();` (etc.) - note the '+' before the '$'.

Comment: You should *always* specify the radix when using `parseInt`

Comment: You should *always* specify the radix when accepting user-typed numbers. If your system doesn't generate hex or octal numbers you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var total_fee = parseInt(registration_fee, 10) + parseInt(material_fee, 10) + parseInt(tuition_fee, 10);
```

Or parseFloat, whichever suits

Answer (score 2):

**Try**

Cast them to numbers using ***Number***

tal_fee = Number(registration_fee) + Number(material_fee) + Number(tuition_fee);

Answer (score 1):

Use `parseInt` to turn the string to int, or `parseFloat` for float.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `parseInt(price) + parseInt(ticket_buyer_fee)` for the variables it works